# How to seed belongs to and has many associantion with seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models. One is categories and the other one is products. I already populated the categories table and now I need to populate the products one with the category id.
I'm using faker for this population.

The models and the seeds.rb file are like this

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end
```

seeds.rb

```
category = Category.ids

100.times do
    Product.create!([{
        name_product: Faker::Commerce.product_name
    },
    {
        value_product: Faker::Commerce.price
    },
    {
        category_id: category.sample
    }
    ])
end
```

But I keep getting the error "validation failed. Categories is necessary" even passing the category id.
If I comment the association inside the product model it works but this isn't a solution.

Comment: Could you confirm your `category` variable (which would be much better renamed to `category_ids` or similar) definitely contains an array of IDs please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in how you are attempting to create the products.

Your current code will attempt to create three products, as you're passing an array of hashes - two of which have no category ID:

```
Product.create!([
  {
    name_product: Faker::Commerce.product_name # << first product, no category
  },
  {
    value_product: Faker::Commerce.price # << second product, no category 
  },
  {
    category_id: category.sample # << third product
  }
])
```

It's a little unclear from your question but try one the following inside your `100.times do` block instead:

```
Product.create!(
    name_product: Faker::Commerce.product_name,
    value_product: Faker::Commerce.price,
    category_id: category.sample
)
```

Or:

```
Product.create!([
  {
    name_product: Faker::Commerce.product_name,
    category_id: category.sample
  },
  {
    value_product: Faker::Commerce.price,
    category_id: category.sample
  },
  {
    category_id: category.sample
  }
])
```

The former will create a single record, if each instance has `name_product`, `value_product` and `category_id` columns; the latter three products, all of which have a `category_id`.

Let me know how you get on and if that helps at all.

---

***Edit***

Looks like your association is setup incorrectly. Try:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: It gives the same error. ActiveRecord :: RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Categories is required

Comment: @lufizi I've updated my answer: I think it's the setup of your associations that's causing the issue. Try the update the bottom section and see if that gets things working.

Comment: Great, glad it helped out!